# Spring WebClient: how to skip/accept Cookie Consent request?

Tags: curl, postman, webclient, spring-webflux, cookieconsent

I'm using Spring WebClient to retrieve the [Forbes Global 2000](https://www.forbes.com/global2000).
It was working fine but now they added a cookie consent modal when trying to access the JSON data at https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/global2000/2020/position/true.json?limit=2000

Technically this is the network flow I can see from Chrome:

1. GET https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/global2000/2020/position/true.json?limit=2000

   curl 'https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/global2000/2020/position/true.json?limit=2000' 
   -H 'authority: www.forbes.com' 
   -H 'pragma: no-cache' 
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' 
   -H 'dnt: 1' 
   -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' 
   -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36' 
   -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' 
   -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' 
   -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' 
   -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' 
   -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' 
   -H 'accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4' 
   --compressed
2. 302 REDIRECT to https://www.forbes.com/consent/?toURL=https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/global2000/2020/position/true.json?limit=2000

[image]

3. This is the consent modal
   [image]
4. POST to https://consent-pref.trustarc.com/defaultpreferencemanager/truste
   when clicking Accept (Accetto)
5. In the network I see no more redirects,but the initial JSON is served:
   [image]

Is there some way I could skip/bypass/accept such a consent using a Spring WebClient?
A curl or postman example would be enough as well.

**UPDATE**

This is the GET which returns the JSON. It has a few cookies, so maybe this way it could work. However, I need to automate it.

```
curl 'https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/global2000/2020/position/true.json?limit=2000' \
  -H 'authority: www.forbes.com' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4' \
  -H 'cookie: notice_behavior=expressed,eu; notice_gdpr_prefs=0,1,2:1a8b5228dd7ff0717196863a5d28ce6c; notice_preferences=2:1a8b5228dd7ff0717196863a5d28ce6c; client_id=8ec8eb2817c5d8913fe8f17384e17644a7e; global_ad_params=%7B%7D; __aaxsc=0; _ga=GA1.2.1634735456.1605525570; _gid=GA1.2.1103122519.1605525570; _fbp=fb.1.1605525570288.36176089; crdl_forbes-livebID=aa58b21d-aa96-4ee0-8340-fb48af0c1a94; crdl_forbes-liveaID=anonimIcgdCVIkNG7BUNba5etK; rbzid=l/U6Jw1r1yWT74cdJuQgosf28tekVPrGz9xIBrFnVQIm5sDTTvTWn/1+r8KTgAdbwgwm63USRoqfI+JwWc3BgQoGTMvyrKX2VRjibHRVHjUSGWqZKX+XhkPhAl2YVYGXbbgLmximPCVub7cvx/UClbnBmD33n1qHOtWLY9urqrdhtD5OGF4BLBZ0L5m0YGx1EKQb+AkPBgt9hT3pryTWI4S84CzcPLIsJTmCtn7YRLgplAvwGe1EA/W8a90o6dER+bVJ+Sy/8/dWswABzRNVwQ==; rbzsessionid=d40c35ba621223231fd16c42b943f00a; __pnahc=0; __tbc=%7Bjzx%7DIFcj-ZhxuNCMjI4-mDfH1NUCZW7-CmMn43P4peooi3pN7s1U6SLs77TJd0_MaIDk7egQVHeoSjUK2k3sjldowD8Ff5A-5DxOArBhtCY3kQmc3ozP8vUOOShHwL0JdQDA3E9l5ifC0NcYbET3aSZxuA; __pat=-18000000; _cb_ls=1; _cb=BLfE4GBNSwJsLxiQ6; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; __qca=P0-1753552556-1605535506773; mnet_session_depth=2%7C1605535504670; aasd=2%7C1605535505885; __pvi=%7B%22id%22%3A%22v-2020-11-16-15-05-06-660-0XYRWHdQ2XYGbaoP-46b9447a9edebf759b8530b76e3d77fb%22%2C%22domain%22%3A%22.forbes.com%22%2C%22time%22%3A1605535556929%7D; xbc=%7Bjzx%7DTSec02msUmzkbggY3uSB4x2gGnm1UBtgCEjruTUCsjodOn-ho2bBitYYAE8Wj1i1AsluUTc70wVCtGSzun5713YJ_vNU7uygAa3M3ny-XzzOp_CsCgfU3k8e_J8gocbcboz88mUS39sdnXYxb82rI1XecPrFioPfHcuQebQwPSy3ueG7x_j8wu6BCd9t0FTHUw-9eIvfWF1WWnXIvcJfs3MZ5QDIUBA9qEt2a7BQs_lhesgShrkv-PkBiPzR60tXNA8DkrlHZF_puETTlo-Xiw; _chartbeat2=.1594934728317.1605535561012.0000000000000001.BFC6ndInmcUBhHH5EC_OdRH7Niui.1; QSI_HistorySession=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.forbes.com%2Fglobal2000%2F%235197f5e1335d~1605525574002%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.forbes.com%2Fglobal2000%2F%234f485ec3335d~1605525601420%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.forbes.com%2Fglobal2000%2F%2367f91b9335d8~1605535512891%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.forbes.com%2Fglobal2000%2F%234c10589f335d~1605535561525' \
  --compressed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to provide some additional cookies with the request.
The minimum set of cookies to get it working is as below:

```
curl 'https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/global2000/2020/position/true.json?limit=2000'
-H 'cookie: notice_behavior=expressed,eu; notice_gdpr_prefs=0,1,2:1a8b5228dd7ff0717196863a5d28ce6c;'   --compressed
```

Since the WebClient was complaining about invalid characters (: and ,)
I ended up with the following minimal cookies set:

```
@Bean
public WebClient forbesWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .defaultCookies(cookies -> {
                cookies.add("notice_behavior", "expressed");
                cookies.add("notice_gdpr_prefs", "0");
            })
            .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(MB5))
            .build();
}
```